# Choral version of Pachelbel Canon in Korean tv

Tags: korean-culture, television

Possibly more about culture than language. Many tv shows use a short segment for choir based on the Pachelbel Canon, usually to underscore moments of epiphany by characters or participants in studio panels. What is the origin of this segment in that form? And is it just 'ah' or are there actually words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are talking about Sanctus by Libera, which is based on Canon by Pachelbel.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmuPJvr89Jw

Many Korean TV programs have been using the introduction part of this song to make the scene holy in fun way. 'Ah' is not a word but after that part, there are some lyrics. https://music.naver.com/lyric/index.nhn?trackId=5204267
Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: It starts with the Latin word _Sanctus_, so I think the excerpts used come from the melisma on that _a_ sound of the first syllable.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's the one. I probably would never have found it otherwise, but I've listened to some of Libera's videos, so I might have stumbled on it. Many of the comments on the video are in Korean, but one in English mentions Running man. I've seen a few episodes of that, but I associate it more with studio-based programs. They usually play only the first section. If I'd heard 'Benedictus qui venit', it might have been easier to track. I have written music for the communion service of the Anglican Church of Korea, but haven't had any takers, there or here in Australia.